# Does calcium nitrate decahydrate dehydrate or decompose upon heating to 100 degrees Celsius?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, heat

Consider a sample of $\ce{Ca(NO3)2.10H2O}$. To remove water, I need to heat it to $\pu{100 ^\circ C},$ but will this high temperature decompose it or will I get the anhydrous salt?

Comment: This information is readily available on the internet, e.g. Wikipedia.

Comment: Are you sure it's a calcium nitrate decahydrate and not a tetrahydrate? Or are you asking about **ammonium** calcium nitrate decahydrate?

Answer (score 1):

Calcium nitrate exists under three forms : 1) $\ce{Ca(NO3)}_2 $ which melts at 361°C; 2) $\ce{Ca(NO3)}_2$$·\ 3 $$\ce{H_2O}$, which is not commercial and melts at 51°C ; 3) $\ce{Ca(NO3)}_2$$·\ 4 $$\ce{H_2O}$ which is commercially available and  melts at 43°C. It looses its water at 132°C and is deliquescent. The decahydrate that you mention does not exist.

Comment: It would be even a better answer if it were backed up by a reputable source.